# Entity Framework Code First: Table with two foreign keys

Tags: foreign-keys, code-first, entity-framework-5

```
 public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }



public class Building
    {
        [Key]
        public int BuildingId { get; set; }
        public string BuildingName { get; set; }
    }

 public class UserBuildings
    {
        //these are the foreign keys
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int BuildingId { get; set; }
        public int BuildingQuantity { get; set; }
    }
```

I've been looking at other examples with two forgein keys but they don't seem to answer my question.

In the UserBuildings table, both the UserId and BuildingId are required to make the record in the UserBuildings table unique. (There will be no two records with the same UserId and BuildingId, although they may have the same of one of them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```
 public class UserResources
    {
        [Key, Column(Order=0)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order=1)]
        public int BuildingId { get; set; }
        public string BuildingName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have tried this before but then there is an SQL database error saying that I can't have two rows with the same value for one of the columns.

Comment: To clarify: The error is when I have two records with the same UserId but a different BuildingId. But I don't want that to give me an error